# Sony Vegas Pro 13 forgets to render some frames in my video

Tags: vegas-pro

I'm not completely sure what's going on here but let me visualize my problem through videos.

[Here's is what my Preview window shows.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQQv80X7gJM)

[And this is what Sony Vegas Pro 13 renders into an .mp4 720p60FPS.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hIoHHU2S4w)

So as you can see, Sony Vegas Pro 13 seems to be skipping a few frames throughout my video, but it only seems to do it where I have very heavy edits as you can notice in the final render.

I am using plugins from Sapphire Genarts OFX, Red Giant Link's Magic Bullet Looks, Boris FX Plugins, and build-in plugins from Sony Vegas Pro 13 itself, is it because there is any incompatibility between the plugins, or is this a bug in the program itself, or should I change anything in my projectsettings, etc?

FYI I have rendered this in 3 possible ways; .avi .mp4 and .avc but so far all 3 of them give me the same result but on different frames throughout the video, but still on the heavily edited parts only.

Comment: What's the frame rate in your project settings? And in your render? 59. 94 or 60?

Comment: @Mulvya My project template is 1280x720p 30FPS and my render is 1280x720 59,940 FPS.

Comment: I just noticed that if I put my project to 59,940, or 60FPS, it seems to be stuck on those exact frames as in my render, anything I can do about it?

Comment: Can you render a small portion surrounding these frames as an image sequence and check?

Comment: @Mulvya I still get the same result.

Comment: Identify a missing frame and render only that. Create a region for that 1 frame only.

Comment: It seems the video clip itself just freezes but the plugins in the clip are still doing their work as I told them to do.

Answer (score 0):

I know this reply is 4 years past, but hopefully its of some use to someone. But I found that matching your project/raw files to match your output fixes that issue for me personally, so if I have a 1080p30fps raw file, the final render needs so also match 1080p30fps, if you "upscale" to 60 fps, you'll have ungodly render times and paused/skipped frames.